# How to calculate information gain for below data set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, information-gain

While understanding information gain calculation - 
The probability of cancer in a population is 1%. A test for cancer correctly identifies cancer patients with a probability of 50% and non cancer patients with a probability of 99.5%. Now I have to calculate information gain obtained using this cancer test? 
This is one of the exercise question I am trying to solve while learning entropy and information gain.
edit - 
My attempt to calculate above is -

If we consider total population as 100 -
 `Cancer patient =1
  Non-cancer patient = 99
  Entropy H = -1/100 log(1/100)- 99/100 log(99/100)`

Now the test on cancer patient gives me -  50% cancer patient and 50% non cancer patient. Hence entropy of classification as cancer patient -

```
H1 = -1/2(log1/2)-1/2log(1/2)
```

Non-cancer patients it gives 99.5% non-cancer patients and .5% cancer .Hence information gain should be. Entropy of classification to non-cancer patient is -

`H2 = -(99.5*99/100)log(99.5*99/100) - (5/100)*99 log(5/100*99)`
I want to know is it correct way to get entropy after test. If this is right the information gain can be calculated -

```
Information gain = H - (H1+H2)
```

Comment: So, what is your first attempt?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have edited my problem  and  stated the solution as per my understanding.Please let me know is it is correct ?